# change default zoom level in sencha touch 2 map

Tags: sencha-touch-2

How to change the default zoom level in sencha touch 2?
Presently I am using code like this

```
  var gmaps={
                xtype    : 'panel',
                height    : Math.ceil(Ext.Element.getDocumentHeight()*.25),
                width    : Math.ceil(Ext.Element.getDocumentWidth()*.96),
                layout:'card',
                items:[{
                    xtype: 'map',
                    useCurrentLocation: true,geo: geo, //Ext.util.Geolocation object
                    useCurrentLocation: geo, //same var geo with geolocation object
                    config: {
                        mapOptions:{
                            zoom: 25,
                            disableDefaultUI: true,
                        //--Available Map Options--//

                            panControl: false,
                            zoomControl: false,
                            mapTypeControl: false,
                            scaleControl: false,
                            streetViewControl: false,
                            overviewMapControl: false 
                        },
```

But even if I change value for zoom, it does not change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you put you `mapOptions` object in a `config` object.

Just remove the config object and you should be all set :

```
xtype: 'map',
useCurrentLocation: true,geo: geo, //Ext.util.Geolocation object
useCurrentLocation: geo, //same var geo with geolocation object
mapOptions:{
    zoom: 25,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
//--Available Map Options--//

    panControl: false,
    zoomControl: false,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    scaleControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    overviewMapControl: false 
},
```

Hope this helped